# Expand function() by another function from another source file

Tags: javascript

My scenario has to do with web client interface, which should work with different hardware. It has a base component, and extensions based on which hardware is attached (in this specific case, the login() procedures differs from device to device).

I am a C++ developer usually, and tasked with this JavaScript extension, and I am completely lost.

The scenario I created which I wanted to test with:

Source1.js (lets say this one is the base interface, and the same for all hardware):

```
function Login() {
    this.type = 'login';
    m_username = 'admin';
    m_password = 'admin';
}

function Constructor() {
    var mClass = new Login();
    this.clicked = function() {
        mClass.clicked();
    }

    this.getLogin = function() {
        return mClass;
    }
}

g_constructor = new Constructor();
```

Source2.js (here the functionality of Login().clicked() should be implemented):

```
function Login() {
    this.clicked = function() {
        document.getElementById("TextHere").innerHTML = m_username + ":" + m_password;
    }
}
```

The HTML File I tested with:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>JavaScript Test</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script src="source1.js"> </script>
        <script src="source2.js"> </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onClick="g_constructor.clicked()">Test</button>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <div id="TextHere">Text</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Usually I would use something like a virtual base class or something, but I have absolutely no idea what to even look for in JavaScript. Can someone give me a hint how to do something like that? Every object of type Login() should have the clicked() function as given in Source2.js

Comment: First thing I notice: in JS you cannot have private members like `m_username`. You must either define them as properties of `this` or use a closure. You could do some search with "closure" in the context of JavaScript.

Comment: But the function clicked() is supposed to be part of the same object (function?), and thus they could be private?

Comment: It's not like that in JS. `m_username` is undefined in your click handler.

Comment: Also the concept of interface does not work like that. Your second source overwrites the previous definition of `Login` (which is lost).

Comment: Can you explain what you expect of `m_username` and `m_password`? If your requirement is that those values (defined in the first source) are only accessible within the final `Login` function, defined in the second source, then... forget it. Not possible in JavaScript. It is either available to all your code in the second source, or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript things work a bit differently. Objects are created with a prototype object. If you define the methods on the prototype object, you can then overwrite those with an actual implementation.

To define methods on the prototype, you should not define them as a property of `this`.

```js
// Code that could be in source file 1
function Login() {
    this.type = 'login';
    this.m_username = 'admin';
    this.m_password = 'admin';
}

function Constructor() {}

Constructor.prototype = new Login();
Constructor.prototype.clicked = function () {
    alert('You should implement the "clicked" method');
};

var g_constructor = new Constructor();

// Code that could be in source file 2 

Constructor.prototype.clicked = function () {
    document.getElementById("TextHere").innerHTML = this.m_username + ":" + this.m_password;
}
```

```html
<button onClick="g_constructor.clicked()">Test</button>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div id="TextHere">Text</div>
```

You'll have noticed that `m_username` is defined as a property of `this`, otherwise it will not be available later: in JS a plain variable (when properly defined with the `var` keyword) is only accessible in the function's scope where it is defined.

Using the more modern ES6 syntax (using `class` and `extends`), it could look like this:

```js
// Code that could be in source file 1
class Login {
    constructor() {
        this.type = 'login';
        this.m_username = 'admin';
        this.m_password = 'admin';
    }
}

class Constructor extends Login {
    clicked () {
        alert('You should implement the "clicked" method');
    }
}

var g_constructor = new Constructor();

// Code that could be in source file 2 

Constructor.prototype.clicked = function () {
    document.getElementById("TextHere").innerHTML = this.m_username + ":" + this.m_password;
}
```

```html
<button onClick="g_constructor.clicked()">Test</button>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div id="TextHere">Text</div>
```

NB: It is not necessary to have the `getLogin` method really, as the `g_constructor` object has all the `Login` members.

Answer (score 0):

javascript is not like c++ it doesn't use the virtual function concept instead you can use composition , you can add methods to an object like this :

```
function A() {
 this.virtualFunction();
  }

A.prototype.virtualFunction = function() {
     alert('A');
   };
 //-------------------------------------

function B() {
      A.call(this);
 }

 B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);
 B.prototype.constructor = B;
 B.prototype.virtualFunction = function() {
      alert('B');
  };

  var b = new B();
```

PS::this is an example that i found on another website

Answer (score 0):

firstly, it is bad idea to separate js functionality into multiple files, but if you so want it, you can change `prototype` of existing class like `Login` and before calling method checks if it exists:

`source1.js`:

```
function Login() {
    this.type = "login";
    this._username = "admin";
    this._password = "admin";
}


function Constructor() {
    var mClass = new Login();

    this.clicked = function() {
        if (Object.getPrototypeOf(mClass).hasOwnProperty("clicked"))
            mClass.clicked();
        else
            console.log("can't click :(");
    }

    this.getLogin = function() {
        return mClass;
    }
}


g_constructor = new Constructor();
```

`source2.js`:

```
Login.prototype.clicked = function() {
    document.getElementById("TextHere").innerHTML = this._username + ":" + this._password;
}
```

also, if you don't want to check it you can just put empty function in your `Login.clicked`:

```
var virtualMethod = function() { console.log("missing implementation!"); }

function Login() {
    this.type = "login";
    this._username = "admin";
    this._password = "admin";

    this.clicked = virtualMethod;
}
```

and change it in second file.